# How to query date in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to query an exact date in elasticsearch and when I submit, I received date that is not part of the query. I have this code

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "device.id": 1374
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "readingType.id": 1048
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "created": "2022-11-16"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 1000,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": [
        {
            "created": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

so I try search date `2022-11-16` and I have this data

[image]

May I know why the elasticsearch add `2022-11-17` to the list? I already checked the documentation but I failed to see the issue of why I have this list. I all I want are the data for `2022-11-16`

I have this setup for my created column.

```
{
    "list": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "reading": {
                "_meta": {
                    "model": "App\\Entity\\List"
                },
                "dynamic_date_formats": [],
                "properties": {
                    "created": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "device": {
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

To query an exact date you need to do it like this:

```
            {
                "range": {
                    "created": {
                       "gte": "2022-11-16",
                       "lte": "2022-11-16"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I do that too. same issue, even doing filter range. I got the same result.

Comment: Can you update your question with the result you get from `GET list/_mapping`?

Comment: Also can you show how you send your query? because even the sort doesn't seem to be respected, which gets me thinking that you might actually not even be sending your query body as you expect.

Comment: yes, I update my post for my mapping setup

Comment: Please answer my two questions above. I'm asking for the real mapping, not the one you think you're using.